# How do I change the default browser?

Tags: firefox, chromium, pidgin, instant-messaging

Despite Chromium being set as my preferred web browser under "System Info", when I click a link in an IM window of Pidgin, it opens in Firefox. How do I make it so that links open in Chromium?

I am running:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- chromium-browser 14.0.835.202~r103287-0ubuntu1
- pidgin 1:2.10.0-0ubuntu2

EDIT:

I also tried `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` and selected chromium (in both auto and manual mode), but after running `sensible-browser &` it still loads Firefox.

Chromium is also set to the default browser within the Chromium -> Preferences -> Default Browser panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed and set my default browser to Chrome stable, `sensible-browser &` opened up Chrome correctly.

It must have just been an issue with Chromium.

Answer (score 13):

If you are on a gnome system, `gnome-www-browser` is checked before `x-www-browser`, so you might have more luck changing this alternative with

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

Comment: This is the real answer.

Answer (score 1):

a first suggestion would be to manually check your preferences by editing the file

```
~/.purple/prefs.xml
```

there you can find the following lines (in the tag pidgin => browsers:

```
<pref name='browser' type='string' value='custom'/>
<pref name='place' type='int' value='0'/>
<pref name='manual_command' type='string' value='sensible-browser'/>
```

I suggest you to have those three lines like they are given in my example.

If this is correct, you should try to run:

```
sensible-browser &
```

from a shell to see whether your preferred browser is setup correctly.

Comment: My `prefs.xml` browser settings file is identical to yours, but when I run `sensible-browser &`, Firefox opens, **not** Chromium.