# Thunderbird uses the wrong browser

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird, browser

I'm unable to make Thunderbird open the default browser.

In the browser preferences, Chromium is selected as the default browser. It's also selected in "Default Applications" in System Settings.

In Thunderbird, I read "Chrome (Default)" which is wrong on all levels:

1. Chrome itself complains that it's not the default browser when I click a link inside Thunderbird.
2. In all other places, that I could find, Chromium is the default

Here is what I tried:

3. I used `update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` to select `chromium-browser` as well (see [How do I change the default browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69669/how-do-i-change-the-default-browser)).
4. And even when I select a different browser from the [list in the Thunderbird preferences](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Changing_the_web_browser_invoked_by_Thunderbird), it **still** opens Chrome.

My current solution is to create a link from `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to `chromium-browser`.

How can I force Thunderbird to use the browser I want???

**EDIT** I also updated **gnome**-www-browser (`update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser`) after feedback from [roadmr](https://askubuntu.com/users/30589/roadmr) but that didn't help. At least `sensible-browser` opens Chromium, now, but Thunderbird is stubborn.

Answer (score 10):

I found the last step missing. You have to go to Edit->Preferences->Advanced->Config Editor and change options

- `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http`
- `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https`

to `true`. Next time when you open a link it will ask you about which browser do you want, and then type `/usr/bin/x-www-browser`.

Comment: As I said in my question, I already changed the preferences you mentioned but this had no effect. For some reason, Thunderbird ignores those settings :-(

Comment: That was the only option that worked for me. Placing the network.protocol-handler.app.http doesnt do anything. You essentially have to ask it to prompt it for you when you open a link... :S

Comment: Weird, but this actually does work. You'll want to mention the fact that these two entries are actually booleans and that you'll want to toggle them to `True`.

Answer (score 4):

Works in Arch Linux, and may work in Ubuntu:

1. (following the answer given here of @Aaron Digulla & @tonicebrian)

   1. search for `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http` in `about:config`
   2. toggle both the `http` and `https` to `true`
2. (following the [suggestion of Raman Gupta on Kevin Locke's Homepage](https://kevinlocke.name/bits/2012/07/18/thunderbird-default-browser-linux/)) when later prompted for your choice of browser, navigate to `/usr/bin/xdg-open` which "will force Thunderbird to use the XDG MIME action (the desktop manager’s default)".

Comment: Thanks! Only this one worked on Debian Jessie with Xfce 4.10 and Icedove.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a somewhat similar problem on Kubuntu 12.04 after installing Chrome. While T-bird continued to open http-protocol links in Firefox, it suddenly began opening https links in Chrome.

Going to Edit-Preferences-Attachments I found the entry for the Content Type http set to firefox, but there was no entry for https.

Using the information I found here, I modified the about:config file for T-bird, with the Config Editor, (found in Edit-Preferences-Advanced-General) to have the network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https use the boolean value of True, thus enabling a user-set value. Upon returning to Edit-Preferences-Attachments I then found an entry for https content and was able to set it to firefox. I found in unnecessary, in my case, to modify network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http

Answer (score 2):

For Thunderbird 102

Open `Settings`, in `General` scroll down until you find `Files & Attachments`.

There should be an entry for `https` that says something like `Use Chromium (default)`.

Click on the dropdown, click on `Use other...` and paste the path to the executable of your browser, for example `/sbin/firefox`.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. And the "network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http" change did not work for me.

After some Googling i found the setting in the thunderbird 
**preferences > Attachments > incoming.**

There i changed the http and the https to the browser of my desire. And it works now.

Comment: Please do not repost answers to multiple questions.  If a question is solved by the same answer, then please mark those questions as duplicates instead.

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark: did you use the update-alternatives procedure to update gnome-www-browser?

```
update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

Comment: Took me a moment to see the difference (**gnome**-www-browser instead of **x**-www-browser) but no game. At least `sensible-browser` now opens chromium, too. What worries me is that Thunderbird ignores its own preferences :-(

Answer (score 0):

Check `xdg-settings get default-web-browser`, it may need adjusting.

Disclaimer: this was found to be the case a Debian system, not an Ubuntu one.