# How do I make Thunderbird open links in Chromium?

Tags: thunderbird, chromium

I want to be able to click links in Thunderbird emails and have them open in Chromium (package name `chromium-browser`). Instead, they open in Firefox.

I have tried the following:

1. xfce preferred applications (Chromium is not listed, so I had to hunt down the executable)
   -- next time I run chromium, it complains that it is no longer the default browser.
2. Telling Chromium to set itself as the default browser. Thunderbird opens links in Firefox.
3. update-alternatives. It's already listed as an alternative at the same priority as Firefox. The "open web browser" app menu item opens Chromium. Thunderbird opens links in Firefox.

I have looked through the entire preferences gui in Thunderbird (but not the advanced config editor yet) and seen nothing that mentions what browser to open links in.

Please note that this is *not* Google Chrome.

Comment: Check this answer. It enables prompt for a browser.

http://askubuntu.com/a/145434/30281

Answer (score 132, accepted):

This is what I found working for me:
You will need to access the "config editor" in Thunderbird itself.

Open Thunderbird. In 24.6.0, the menu can be accessed on the right hand side of the top menu bar (next to the search bar and is represented by three horizontal lines).

Click *Edit* > then click *Preferences* >, 
a new window will open. You will need to select the  *Advanced*  tab, at the bottom of that tab Open the *Config Editor*.

Then, search for both **`network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http`** and
**`network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https`**.

These two are most likely to have a current value of **`false`**. Change the value to **`true`** (do this by simply right clicking on them) and the next time you try to open a link from some e-mail it'll ask you which browser to use. Chromium isn't likely to be shown in the list of choices, so use the navigate button. You can find Chromium at **`/usr/bin/chromium-browser`**.

If using google chrome as your browser of choice you may want to make it `/usr/bin/google-chrome`  or `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`
If Thunderbird doesn't ask you which browser to use when you click on a link after doing this, you can try deleting **mimeTypes.rdf** file in your profile folder to reset it. The profile folder is typically found as `~/.thunderbird/xxxxxxxx.default/`

[Original text by Htbaa](http://blog.htbaa.com/news/use-an-alternative-browser-to-open-links-in-thunderbird-7-xubuntu-11-10)

Comment: Removing the mimeTypes.rdf files was necessary for this to work for me. I used `locate mimeTypes.rdf` to find all of them.

Comment: This worked for me+1. Finally. System default setting is not properly taken into account as documented on http://kb.mozillazine.org/Default_browser#KDE for Kubuntu.

Comment: Confirmed to work as of Thunderbird 31.7.0. The handlers for `https` and `http` respectively can be set in Options -> Attachments -> Incoming (loo for the protocol name there).

Comment: This is supposed to make it prompt for the browser. The requirement is to force Tbird to open chromium-browser always, never Firefox.

Comment: This is still how you do it in version 68.8.0

Comment: I'd like Thunderbird to open link in Chrome, which is my default browser. Better stated, I'd like and expect Thunderbird to open links in the default browser, which for me is Chrome. I looked for network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http[s] and they were both already true, yet Thunderbird doesn't prompt me to choose the browser and uses Firefox which is not the default.

Comment: And kind of unsurprisingly, deleting mimeTypes.rdf didn't work either

Comment: Obsolete as of 2022.

Comment: For me it worked for Google Chrome, too.

Answer (score 14):

In Thunderbird 11.0.1, it is simple, yet not intuitive:

1. Go to Preferences (Menu *Edit* → *Preferences*).
2. Click on the *Attachments* tab.
3. In the *Content Type and Action* section set *HTTPS*, *HTTP*, and *FTP* to *Use google-chrome* (or other desired browser).

That worked for me after trying numerous things in terminal that did not work.

Comment: Found this [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-users/2010-September/052349.html) and can confirm that it works. This was necessary for me after installing Firefox. Before it worked for me using the *warn-external* config approach.

Comment: NIce, works for me too.

Comment: Does not work for me on Ubuntu16.04: the "Content Type" does not contain "HTTPS, HTTP and FTP". Instead it only contains "plain text document".

Answer (score 11):

Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> General -> Config Editor...

**Right click** -> **New** -> **String**

Enter the preference name:

```
network.protocol-handler.app.http
```

Value:

```
/usr/bin/x-www-browser
```

**Setting Default Browser**

In the command line, type

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser && sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

Comment: Helpful to use `x-www-browser`; however setting the above preference didn't make a difference for me - setting the warn value as recommended by Vitaly did

Comment: The handlers for `https` and `http` respectively can be set in Options -> Attachments -> Incoming (loo for the protocol name there).

Comment: Strange, AKSiS's method doesn't work on my Windows 7 system(Thunderbird 24), and Vitaly's method works fine.

Comment: "network.protocol-handler.app.http" has been removed.  I did this first step with "vi" instead (as recommended at mozillazine.com) and found the result in Invalidprefs.js.

Answer (score 6):

## Solution for the newest Thunderbird version 68.10 and upwards

There is a file now called `handlers.json` in your `????????.default` profile directory under `~/.thunderbird`.

Edit or create this file with a text editor while Thunderbird is closed.

Setting `"action": 2` and adding `{"name":"xdg-open","path":"/usr/bin/xdg-open"}` to the first position of the pertaining HTTP and/or HTTPS `"handlers: []"` list, will launch the default browser or program as specified by the desktop environment.

The `handlers.json` file should look then like this for the [Vivaldi browser](https://vivaldi.com/):

```
{"defaultHandlersVersion":{},"mimeTypes":{"text/plain":{"action":2,"handlers":[{"name":"gvim","path":"/home/bin/gvim"}],"extensions":["asc","txt","text","pot","brf","srt"]},"application/pdf":{"action":4,"ask":true,"extensions":["pdf"]}},"schemes":{"https":{"action":2,"handlers":[{"name":"vivaldi-stable","path":"/usr/bin/vivaldi-stable"}]},"http":{"action":2,"handlers":[{"name":"vivaldi-stable","path":"/usr/bin/vivaldi-stable"}]}}}
```

Preceding mimetypes are for text and PDF.

## Solution for newer Thunderbird versions

[image]

## Solution for older versions using find

1.Thunderbird → Edit → Preferences → Advanced → <kbd>Config Editor…</kbd>:

```
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http = true
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https = true
```

2.Close Thunderbird.

3.At the command line, type:

```
$ find ~/.thunderbird/ -name mimeTypes.rdf -delete
```

4.Reopen Thunderbird and click on an HTTP(S)-link. A `Launch Application` window will open. Click on <kbd>Choose…</kbd>.

5.Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to directly enter a `/usr/bin/` path to your favourite browser executable, e.g.: `/usr/bin/vivaldi-stable`

6.Check  `Remember my choice for http(s) links.`

7.<kbd>Open link</kbd>

Comment: would you mind to specify the version of `the newest Thunderbird version` as a number? Mine is `68.10.0 (64-bit)` and I don't see a file called handlers.json on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @woodz I have added the version number and provided a detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have never used thunderbird but, this looks right -->

When you click on a web link in Thunderbird, it invokes the default web browser for the operating system. It is possible to change this behavior by changing the default browser.
On Linux, another way (tried with TB1.5 under Suse and Debian) is to insert the following line in Thunderbird's prefs.js or user.js file (of course put in the correct path to your firefox):

**user_pref("network.protocol-handler.app.http", "/usr/bin/firefox");**

You can find where Chromium is by typing -->

```
which chromium
```

into the terminal.

Source -->

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Changing_the_web_browser_invoked_by_Thunderbird

Comment: Option (1) in my original question worked -- I previously allowed Chromium to set itself as default, which makes exo-open think there's no default browser. If I point the system default at the Chromium executable, and tell Chromium to stfu, then Thunderbird happily opens it for urls in emails. Obviously Chromium and Ubuntu are thinking two different things about the concept of default browser. Thanks!

Comment: PS -- this answer also worked, which is why I marked it correct. I just prefer not editing files that say DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE at the top if I can beat the problem into submission another way.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this solution and it worked:

1) In Settings Manager switch your favourite browser as default browser.

2) update-alternatives --config x-www-browser

3) Follow steps written [here](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Open_URL%27s_in_Thunderbird_in_favorite_browser_in_XFCE)

Comment: Step `#2`, replacing the content of `mimeTypes.rdf` with [that given](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Open_URL's_in_Thunderbird_in_favorite_browser_in_XFCE) is what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Because none of the listed solutions worked for me, here a different, very drastic way of getting the application to open links in `Thunderbird` changed:

(E.g. if links currently are opened with `Firefox`)

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox-esr
```

--> open `Thunderbird` and click on some link --> you can choose a different browser now. Now we can re-install `Firefox`

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```

Comment: Or like this: `sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox-saved` then open link in thunderbird. Choose Chrome, then `sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox-saved /usr/bin/firefox`.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I ran thunderbird using strace, and discovered, that regardless of what value I chose for **network.protocol-handler.app.http**, it was always attempting to launch /usr/bin/google-chrome. I searched the preferences, and was unable to find any place where this was defined. In the end, I just did: **ln -s chromium-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome** , and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: hmm, a slimy hack to handle what seems to be a slimy hack in Thunderbird, lol.

Comment: This will have quite the side effect! Use Vitaly's solution below.

Answer (score 0):

There is one other Thunderbird setting you need to check.

Preferences - Attachments - Incoming

The http and https settings there override the OS default and telling Chromium to make itself the default browser.

See this bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724461

And this for the gory details about how the default browser is determined in Thunderbird:
http://kevinlocke.name/bits/2012/07/18/thunderbird-default-browser-linux/

Answer (score 0):

This may help anyone stumbling across this later who has it stuck to Firefox

Go to settings control panel, `System -> MIME Type Editor`, and set each to 'Web Browser':

```
application/x-extension-html, application/x-extension-shtml, application/x-extension-xhtml, application/xhtml+xml, text/html
```

Then in settings control panel, Personal -> Preferred Applications, choose chrome

Run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`
and choose Chrome

Then launch `/usr/bin/x-www-browser` and it should start chrome

Then try in Thunderbird.

Comment: No wonder my CPU usage went crazy when i was clicking on links in TB, those settings were sending it to Thunderbird making a inf loop

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` I get `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x-www-browser`

Answer (score 0):

I have never posted to any message board ever for over 10 years, but I thought I should share a solution here.

I only switched to linux (mint, cinnamon at first and now xfce) 1.5 years ago.

For that entire time, I have been on a never-ending quest to somehow force thunderbird to open web links in the browser of my choice *and* always in a new window, not a new tab.

Many times I have read about changing the settings of these to true:

network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http = true
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https = true

This never did anything for me, until today, when I finally tried something new.  I have tried many, many times to *edit* my handlers.json file in my thunderbird user dir, and I was able to change the default browser for web links (my choice was chromium-browser), but I could never get it to accept the --new-window switch.

TWO DISCOVERIES:

1. If you rename the handlers.json, thunderbird WILL ask you what program to use to open your web link with, as the two above settings tell it to, because thunderbird makes a new handlers.json file and creates its contents from scratch.
2. If you create a bash script file (that you make sure to make executable) with these two lines as its contents:

## !/bin/bash

chromium-browser --new-window "$@"

and tell thunderbird to open web links with this script file, this works beautifully.

Sorry for the brute amateur posting and information, but this problem has haunted me for EVER, and I imagine that someone else out there might appreciate knowing about these two discoveries.

:-)

Comment: Linux Mint is not Ubuntu. It is of topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to do the same with Chrome and none of the answers worked for me.

What did work was running this single command from a terminal:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop
```

Note that it did not work without the `.desktop` extension. I have no idea why and I do *not* have a google-chrome.desktop file in my home folder (which was the current directory while running the above command) or anywhere in my path. It probably does exist somewhere.

This setting has persisted across reboot.

Note that Chrome was already my default browser, in that Chrome itself said it was the default browser, and every other application except from thunderbird was opening links in Chrome. However I did find out that `xdg-open` was opening urls in Firefox, and indeed the output of `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` was `firefox` (I had never set that and I had never chosen Firefox as browser for anything; this is a very recent fresh install of OpenSUSE; that either came out of the box or was set by Thunderbird itself).

So maybe there are two or more concepts of "default browser": the one defined by `xdg-utils`, which I haven't found a single application depending on except for Thunderbird, and then a more widely recognized one which I have no idea where it is stored, which Chrome itself recognizes as the way to establish itself as the default browser and that every other application I've ever clicked a link in understands.

I realize I provide no background and I'm asking more questions than I answer, however this does provide an answer that worked for me, and the only one that did.

Actually this is for Chrome, so I cannot guarantee this works for Chromium, but it definitely seems like it's applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to use one of the methods above, but this worked for me (as of 2022-05-20) on Kubuntu linux 22.04:

- edit configs, change `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http` and `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https` to `true`
- click on an http and then an https link in thunderbird; for each, a dialog will appear
- **importantly**, in the dialog do not simply change it to "Firefox" (this worked once for me, but not thereafter). **Instead**: browse to /snap/bin/firefox (which is where firefox now lives in *buntu, I take it) and check "always open" with this app

(Note: I had to delete (i.e. rename) my handlers.json because once it was set the "warn" configs no longer had an effect, and setting it through the GUI also didn't change anything. This may have side effects for other handlers, so be warned.)

If instead I used the "Firefox" option that was already in the dialog, the handlers.json file would be updated with values that did not work. I would get errors of this sort in the Thunderbird stdout console (I might have the formatting slightly wrong here):
`env: "http://blah.com" No such file or directory`
...which makes sense if you see what it was trying to run (below).

The **non-functioning** handlers.json (just the "schemes" section):

```
        "https": {
            "action": 2,
            "handlers": [
                {
                    "name": "Firefox Web Browser",
                    "command": "env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop /snap/bin/firefox %u"
                }
            ]
        },
        "http": {
            "action": 2,
            "handlers": [
                {
                    "name": "Firefox Web Browser",
                    "command": "env %u"
                }
            ],
            "ask": true
        }
    }
```

The **functioning** handlers.json, after I did things the way I described above:

```
        "https": {
            "action": 2,
            "handlers": [
                {
                    "name": "firefox",
                    "path": "/snap/bin/firefox"
                }
            ]
        },
        "http": {
            "action": 2,
            "handlers": [
                {
                    "name": "firefox",
                    "path": "/snap/bin/firefox"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had the exact same "env %u" junk in my handlers.json (since 22.04?), which I could simply fix by removing the file. This left me with a generated schemes section containing nothing but `"action":4` and it works just like the explicit binding. BUT now every start of thunderbird opens 6 browser tabs with requests to services.addons.thunderbird.net and others. Any idea what's misguiding thunderbird here? Even "welcome" is displayed externally.

Comment: The cause behind "thunderbird opens 6 browser tabs with requests to services.addons.thunderbird.net and others" was not in `handlers.json` but a bogus preferences in `prefs.js`, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1446163/436826

Answer (score 0):

Serge Stroobandt's answer is the full: https://askubuntu.com/a/172883/646650
Under Linux the

```
~/.thunderbird/xxxxx.default/
```

folder the json file must to be edited too.

With your favorite editor open the handlers.json file. Eg.:

```
kate ~/.thunderbird/xxxxx.default/handlers.json
```

Search all strings to beginning with "http". And change

```
"Firefox webbrowser","command":"firefox %u"
```

part to (eg. if you want Brave Browser to use):

```
"Brave Web Browser","command":"/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable %u"
```

Don't forget to change string where the "https" text is.
Note: also you can change to any web browser what you want to use. You can find the full path of your browsers using "whereis" command.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same issue. And the "network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http" change did not work for me.

After some Googling i found the setting in the thunderbird **preferences > Attachments > incoming**.

There i changed the http and the https to the browser of my desire. And it works now.

Comment: Please do not repost answers to multiple questions.  If a question is solved by the same answer, then please mark those questions as duplicates instead.

Comment: -1: another answer that was already posted 3 years before you posted this answer already gave this information.