# Changing default browser in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, default-browser

xubuntu comes with Firefox as a default browser. I however prefer opera and would like to make it my default browser. Example: I click a link in Thunderbird and would like it to open in Opera and not in Firefox, as it is now.. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 12):

In XFCE you can change the default browser (and other default applications like the File manager or the e-mail client) using the main menu: <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Settings Manager</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferred Applications</kbd>

Comment: Yes, that is it. It is Settings/Settings Manager/Preffered Applications. Thank you laurent!

Comment: Sorry for the wrong menu names... I will correct. My version is not in English :)

Comment: The problem is that it **does not work** at least in two cases:
1) opening a link in _Thunderbird_ still launches Firefox
2) running _"ubuntu-bug"_ also opens Firefox

Any soulution which would cover all the cases? :/

(using Xubuntu 15.04, clean install; using _Chromium_ as default browser)

Thanks for help!

Comment: This http://askubuntu.com/a/367820/208566 has solved the problem

Comment: PS: still changing it also in xfce4-settings-manager -> Preferred Applications is needed

Comment: None of the above works with Thunderbird. See http://askubuntu.com/a/172883/7304 for a Thunderbird specific working solution.

Comment: It does not work for me. I have BBrave as a Browser. I've done this, but still whenever I click on a link (ie: PDFs) they are opened in Firefox ... not a clue ...

Comment: It's now called "Default Applications".