# Thunderbird / Lightning no longer detecting caldav calendars (since Kubuntu 22.04)

Tags: kubuntu, thunderbird, calendar

I have been using caldav calendars in thunderbird for quite some time, but since the upgrade to Kubuntu 22.04 I can't get it to work any more, while on another machine still running 20.04 the same works without problems. Just now I upgraded the 22.04 machine to 22.10 but no difference.

When I enter user and URL and press **Find Calendars** nothing is found and all I can see in the logs is this:

```
console.warn: Calendar: [CalICSProvider] Could not detect calendar using method attemptHead
console.warn: Calendar: [CalICSProvider] Could not detect calendar using method attemptGet
console.warn: Calendar: [CalICSProvider] Could not detect calendar using method attemptDAVLocation
console.warn: Calendar: [CalICSProvider] Could not detect calendar using method attemptPut
console.warn: Calendar: [CalDavProvider] Could not detect calendar using method attemptLocation
console.warn: Calendar: [CalDavProvider] Could not detect calendar using method wellKnown
console.warn: Calendar: [CalDavProvider] Could not detect calendar using method attemptRoot
console.error: Calendar: 
Error during calendar detection: resource:///modules/calendar/utils/calProviderDetectionUtils.jsm:20: NoneFoundError
DetectionError@resource:///modules/calendar/utils/calProviderDetectionUtils.jsm:20:1
@resource:///modules/calendar/utils/calProviderDetectionUtils.jsm:31:7
detect@resource:///modules/calendar/utils/calProviderDetectionUtils.jsm:164:26
```

At the same time when this stopped working, also `handlers.json` was broken, which just now I fixed by removing that file and starting from a default generated version. Given that both features relate to accessing some https url I just thought there *might* be a connection.

Any ideas where I should be looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there was indeed a common cause:

While previously struggling with a problem that looked like https://superuser.com/questions/1122787/clicking-a-https-link-in-thunderbird-does-not-open-the-link-in-the-browser (in my case the update to kubuntu 22.04 had caused thunderbird to completely stop opening links in firefox), I had fiddled with preferences like `network.protocol-handler.external-default`. After removing that and similar preferences from `prefs.js` now, things are back to normal: I can connect to calendars on the net and links in mails open in my default browser.

I can only guess that the effect of those preferences has changed since the answers in an around that other thread.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was an inadvertently enabled HTTP proxy.